# Word/term for persistence in incorrect pronunciation

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, terminology, idiom-requests

Is there a word or idiom for persistence in pronouncing words incorrectly, even after being corrected?

Specifically, this question has arisen from a teenage debate over the correct pronunciation of "Reese's", as in peanut butter cups. Some persist in saying "Reesees", despite having been given proof that it is the possessive of *Reese* and should be pronounced as such.

Trivial debate, I know, but it brought up an interesting question.

Comment: There is no "correct" with regard to proper names, particularly ones that are trademarks. They can protect their own pronunciation if they care about it; it's certainly not anybody else's problem. I imagine the Reese people are happy to be pronounced any way at all as long they're being bought.

Comment: @John I’d say it’s the exact opposite: proper names are the **only** place where there can ever be a ‘correct’ pronunciation, particularly personal names.

Comment: Personal names, certainly. But not trademarked names. Anybody who wants to can pronounce a trademarked name any way they like.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's not that simple - http://www.duetsblog.com/2014/08/articles/trademarks/trademark-pronunciation/

Answer (score 28):

#### Mumpsimus

I think this is described almost perfectly by the word ***[mumpsimus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mumpsimus)***:

> 1. adherence to or persistence in an erroneous use of language, memorization, practice, belief, etc., out of habit or obstinacy (opposed to *sumpsimus*).
> 2. a person who persists in a mistaken expression or practice (opposed to *sumpsimus*).
>
> #### Origin of mumpsimus
>
> 1520-30; from a story, which perhaps originated with Erasmus, of an illiterate priest who said *mumpsimus* rather than *sumpsimus* (1st plural perfect indicative of Latin *sumere* to pick up; see *consume*) while reciting the liturgy, and refused to change the word when corrected
>
> (Dictionary.com Unabridged; Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2017.)

Comment: I’ve always found it hard to keep *mumpsimus* walled off from *sumpsimus*.

Comment: I am going to pronounce this ""moomp-SY-mis" regardless of what you tell me.  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

A possibility is *mishearing.*

Call it *mishearing* as in the example *buttonhold* became over time *buttonholed* because it was misheard.

*Reese's* might fall into the category of mishearing and became *Reesees*.